# Passing map from controller

Tags: grails, dictionary, groovy

I am trying to pass a map that is being created from specific values that have been clicked on and send it to my view page so that it will populate my table with the specific days from the choices I made. But no matter what I do it will not pass my map into the controller. I send a query to retrieve the values for my controller and then place it into a map to then send it to my view page through `[finalMap: finalMap]` but it does not allow me to call it in my view page.

Here is the function in my controller handling the results from the query and placing them into a map:

```
    def testFunction = {

    def days = Utility.executeQuery("select date from Utility where week_id = ${params.utility.week_id}")

    def testMap = days
    def map = testMap.collect{[it, it]}
    def finalMap = map.listIterator().reverse().collectEntries()

    [finalMap: finalMap]
    }
```

Even though I have it in a map it cannot call it from my view page as seen here:

```
    <table id="mondayTimeSelection" border width = 450 height=200>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <g:each in="${finalMap}" var="e"><th style="text-align: center; width: 115px;">${e.key}</th></g:each>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

How can I pass this map to my controller successfully from my function in my controller? Or is there another way I should be going about this?

Comment: What error do you get? Have you tried printing out finalMap in the controller before calling the view to see what's in it?

Comment: I get errors on my GSP where it says it cannot resolve the symbol `finalMap`. But i have printed out the results of finalMap in the controller and it's correct.

Comment: Is your gsp named correctly (i.e. `testFunction.gsp`)? Or is the view code shown above from a template included in `testFunction.gsp`?

Comment: My GSP is named correctly as list.gsp, because that is the view function in my controller. I have 3 other functions aside from my list function inside my controller. One of which is testFunction.

Comment: If your gsp is labeled list.gsp - that might be the problem. Relabel it testFunction.gsp   - from the code you have displayed, testFunction IS a view function in your controller.

Comment: Does the `list` function call `testFunction` and use the results? If so please add the code for the `list` function.

Answer (score 0):

You've validated that it does show up in the controller?
When I force a map into finalMap - the page works for me.
I.e:

```
   def testFunction = {

    def finalMap = ["test": "test", "test2":"Test2"]

    [finalMap: finalMap]
    }
```

Comment: Yes I have. I had the controller print out `finalMap` and it contains the correct entries for what the map should have.

Comment: Because I set up a controller put that test function in, and your code in a gsp and it rendered both entries (test and test2) - try having the gsp print out final map?  What version of grails are you using?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to have the GSP iterate through my finalMap when it gets passed into and and then print each of the values in my table. But `finalMap` is never passed to the GSP

Comment: No - try in the gsp doing   ${finalMap}.  Something else to try - try my testFunction - does it work for you?  Because it does in mine environment using your gsp code.

Comment: I already have that in my GSP:
`<g:each in="${finalMap}" var="e"><th style="text-align: center; width: 115px;">${e.key}</th></g:each>`

I tried your testFunction and it still did not work. I'm currently using the latest IntelliJ 12.1.2

Comment: Is the project checked in anywhere I can see it?  I think the problem is somewhere else.